# Collect Map.Entry first value into map

Tags: java, collections, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have following map :

```
private static Map<String, String[]> createMap(){
    Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("A", new String[]{null});
    map.put("B", new String[]{"Banana"});
    map.put("C", new String[]{""});
    map.put("D", new String[]{"Duck"});
    return map;
}
```

I want to convert this map into `Map<String, String>`

Needed Output :

> Key :B Value : Banana
>
> Key :D Value : Duck

I want to do this using `Java 8 Stream APIs` and and one of the solution that I tried is

```
final Map<String, String[]> collect = createMap().entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue()[0] != null && !"".equals(e.getValue()[0]))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

collect.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println("Key :" + key + " Value :" + Arrays.toString(value)));
```

But this is giving me `Map<String, String[]>` and output is

> Key :B Value :[Banana]
>
> Key :D Value :[Duck]

**How can I tell Collector to only extract the first value from `Map.Entry` values ?**

Comment: how about an input `"A", new String[]{null, "Apple"}`? Is this possible? If yes, what is the expected output?

Comment: As only first element should be considered, this input should be skipped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
          .filter(entry -> Stream.of(entry.getValue()[0])
                                .anyMatch(s -> s != null && !s.isEmpty()))
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> entry.getValue()[0]))
```

by your code:

```
Map<String, String> collect = map.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue()[0] != null && !e.getValue()[0].isEmpty())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry->entry.getValue()[0]));
```

Comment: I don’t see the advantage of turning the test for the first array element into an `allMatch` that would test other unrelated elements when there are some. But turning `"".equals(e.getValue()[0])` into `e.getValue()[0].isEmpty()` is a good idea.

Comment: @Holger, You are right, OP solution with the changes that you pointed out is better.